# IE: click event on a div placed over an image

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser

i have a div placed over an image, and i want to catch the onclick event of the div, it is working fine on chrome and FF but not on IE.
on IE when i click the div, it is calling the imgclicked() function.
if i add a background-color:red to the div, it works fine (calls divclicked()), but i don't want to have a color. i tried "transparent" but still not working!

```
<body>
    <img id="img1" src="img/img1.png" style="z-index:10;" ondblclick="imgclicked()" />
    <div id="maindmdtpc" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0; width: 500px ;height:20px;border:2px solid red;z-index:9999;" ondblclick="divclicked()" >

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you try the z-index property?

Comment: what happens if you position the image relatively?  Does this fix it, if not it may be the empty container IE bug in which case you will need to make a transparent image (gif or png) of at least 50x50 px and use that as the background of the div

Comment: @Chanchal: i tried the z-index as u can see in the code, but didn't work.

Comment: @Pete: thanks i will try your suggestions

Comment: Add a transparent gif / png as the background. I've had this issue myself.

Comment: @Pete it doesn't need to be 50x50. 1x1 is fine. It just needs to be repeated

Comment: @3rror404 I found different versions of IE needed different sizes - 50x50 worked for all versions though

Comment: Thanks all,
done by adding transparent image,
u can add it as an answer :)